# Oracle DB ORDER BY and ROWNUM Inverting Order?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing an Oracle SQL statement to fetch a value by the most recent date. If my table looks like this:

```
+============+=================+
| sv_version | sv_date_applied |
+============+=================+
| 7.3.0      | 13-JUL-2014     |
+------------+-----------------+
| 7.4.0      | 13-JUL-2014     |
+------------+-----------------+
```

... and my SQL statement looks like this:

```
SELECT sv_version FROMtblSchemaVersion ORDER BY sv_date_applied DESC;
```

... I get:

```
+============+
| sv_version |
+============+
| 7.4.0      |
+------------+
| 7.3.0      |
+------------+
```

...but when I try to get the top row (7.4.0), like this:

```
SELECT sv_version, ROWNUM FROM tblSchemaVersion WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY sv_date_applied DESC;
```

... I get:

```
+============+========+
| sv_version | ROWNUM |
+============+========+
| 7.3.0      | 1      |
+------------+--------+
```

Why does `ROWNUM` change the order of the rows? I assumed it would work like SQL Server's `TOP` or MySQL's `LIMIT` statements?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: When is ROWNUM assigned it's value? What is the result of:

    `SELECT sv_version,  sv_date_applied, ROWNUM
     FROM tblSchemaVersion 
     ORDER BY sv_date_applied DESC`

Comment: "*I assumed it would work like SQL Server's TOP*". Don't assume -  read the manual. It's all explained there: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work like `TOP`.

Oracle applies the `ROWNUM` before the `ORDER BY`.

What you need is

```
SELECT ROWNUM, sv_version FROM
  ( 
    SELECT
    sv_version  
    FROM tblSchemaVersion 
    ORDER BY sv_date_applied DESC
  )
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Please see this [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b9c7/2) to see how it works

Comment: Thank you, but, unfortunately, the result is no different. Leaving off the `WHERE` clause causes the `ROWNUM` to become numbered correctly, but `WHERE` still pulls back 7.3.1.

Comment: @spryno724 your sample shows only date without its time portion, and the dates are equal. check time part of your `sv_date_applied`. probably 7.3.1 is actually the latest one?

Comment: It is also possible that the dates are exactly equal in which case Oracle will decide for itself which record it chooses

Comment: My understanding of DATE fields were that the time was stored, as well, but not displayed. Dropping `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` will always cause the `7.4.0` to display at the top, but adding it back in still picks  the `7.3.1`.

Comment: so try displaying the full date and time and see what it shows you

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your `ROWNUM = 1` predicate is applied before the `ORDER BY`.  The statement

```
SELECT sv_version, ROWNUM 
  FROM tblSchemaVersion 
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1 
 ORDER BY sv_date_applied DESC;
```

is saying "Give me an arbitrary row from the table, I don't care which one.  Then sort my 1 row result set by `sv_date_applied`".  Obviously, that's not what you want.  You want the `ROWNUM` predicate to be applied after the sort.  So you would want something like

```
SELECT sv_version
  FROM (SELECT sv_version
          FROM tblSchemaVersion
         ORDER BY sv_date_applied DESC) 
 WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, Rownum is a psuedocolumn which is applied to the rows selected by the query.

As **where clause** is executed before the **order by** clause

In Second Query, 
SELECT sv_version, ROWNUM FROM tblSchemaVersion WHERE ROWNUM = 1 ORDER BY sv_date_applied DESC;

**First part:**

SELECT sv_version, ROWNUM FROM tblSchemaVersion
will give result:

```
| sv_version |
+============+
| 7.3.0      |
+------------+
| 7.4.0      |
+------------+
```

as where executes first which gives results as

```
| sv_version |
+============+
| 7.3.0      |
+------------+
```

and then order by clause will run for only one row so thats why the results

Comment: Your result sets do not match your query, which might confuse some readers.

Answer (score 0):

You might also try a more Standard SQL compliant version using ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT sv_version 
FROM
  ( 
    SELECT
       sv_version,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY sv_date_applied DESC) rn
    FROM tblSchemaVersion 
  )
WHERE rn = 1
```

This way you can also get the 2nd row or the max row for each group...

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH  MRDW_2
 AS (SELECT * FROM   TABLE1
   ORDER BY
     case when :dir_param = '0'  then LONGNAM end,
     case when :dir_param <>'0'  then LONGNAM end desc
       ),
 MRDW     
 AS   (select * from MRDW_2
     WHERE ROWNUM=1)


SELECT * FROM MRDW;
```